# Отсортировать массив js

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Как отсортировать такой массив с эелементами списка по значению по алфавиту?

```
<li name="Дн026" id="Т_26" class="hood" style="display: none;">20 лет Победы</li>
<li name="Дн025" id="Т_25" class="hood" style="display: none;">Семафорная</li>
<li name="Дн018" id="Т_18" class="hood" style="display: none;">Платонова</li>
<li name="Дн015" id="Т_15" class="hood" style="display: none;">Карла Маркса</li>
<li name="Дн014" id="Т_14" class="hood" style="display: none;">Пастера</li>
<li name="Дн080" id="Т_80" class="hood" style="display: none;">Глинки</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- взять все `li` из `ul`
- отсортировать их по `textContent`
- вставить обратно в `ul` в отсортированном порядке

Пример реализации на базе [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7742404/3432401):

```js
var parent = document.querySelector("ul");
var elements = parent.querySelectorAll("li");
var sortedElements = Array.from(elements).sort(function(a, b) {
  var c = a.textContent;
  var d = b.textContent;
  return c < d ? -1 : c > d ? 1 : 0;
});
for (let element of sortedElements) {
  parent.appendChild(element);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li name="Дн026" id="Т_26" class="hood">20 лет Победы</li>
  <li name="Дн025" id="Т_25" class="hood">Семафорная</li>
  <li name="Дн018" id="Т_18" class="hood">Платонова</li>
  <li name="Дн015" id="Т_15" class="hood">Карла Маркса</li>
  <li name="Дн014" id="Т_14" class="hood">Пастера</li>
  <li name="Дн080" id="Т_80" class="hood">Глинки</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: зачем было добавлять 2 лишних переменных c и d я не понял.@Regent

Comment: @Избытоксусликов чтобы строка с `return`-ом получилась компактной

Comment: спасибо @Regent

Comment: @Избытоксусликов чтобы ресурсов больше использовать. Думаю в возврате `0` здесь вообще смысла нет.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev две локальные переменные - это не огромные затраты памяти. А ноль - для соответствия стандартному поведению функции сравнения.

Comment: @Regent Спасибо большое!

Answer (score -1):

```js
var cnt = document.getElementById('cnt');
var list = document.querySelectorAll('.hood');

cnt.innerHTML = [].slice.call(list).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.textContent > b.textContent ? 1 : -1;
}).map(function(elm) {
  return elm.outerHTML;
}).join('');
```

```html
<ul id="cnt">
  <li name="Дн026" id="Т_26" class="hood">20 лет Победы</li>
  <li name="Дн025" id="Т_25" class="hood">Семафорная</li>
  <li name="Дн018" id="Т_18" class="hood">Платонова</li>
  <li name="Дн015" id="Т_15" class="hood">Карла Маркса</li>
  <li name="Дн014" id="Т_14" class="hood">Пастера</li>
  <li name="Дн080" id="Т_80" class="hood">Глинки</li>
</ul>
```

Логика вся как в ответе Regent, только покомпактнее и всё содержимое ul сразу.